# IasPager pager not working after ajax update on clistview

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, yii-extensions

Yii infinite scroll extention: "IasPager pager"  not working after ajax update on clistveiw.
It's working fine before ajax call but after ajax call when i update listview it's not working.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
   'id' => 'VideoList',
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'itemView' => '_view',
   'template' => '{items} {pager}',
   'pager' => array(
                'class' => 'ext.infiniteScroll.IasPager', 
                'rowSelector'=>'.row', 
                'listViewId' => 'VideoList', 
                'header' => '',
                'loaderText'=>'Loading...',
                'options' => array('history' => false, 'triggerPageTreshold' => 2, 'trigger'=>'Load more'),
              )
        )
   );
```

Comment: please help if any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution of this, it works fine.

```
<?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'itemView'=>'/products/viewProductList',
                    'summaryText'=>false,
                    'emptyText'=>"<p> Coming Soon!!</p>",
                    'id'=>'ajaxProductListView',
                    'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/mycustom.css',

                   'template' => '{items} {pager}',
                   'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
                    'pager' => array(
                        'class' => 'ext.infiniteScroll.IasPager', 
                        'rowSelector'=>'.ademo', 
                        'listViewId' => 'ajaxProductListView', 
                        'header' => '',
                        'loaderText'=>'Loading',
                        'options' => array('history' => false, 'triggerPageTreshold' => 1, 'trigger'=>'Load more'),
                    ),
                'afterAjaxUpdate'=>"function(id, data) {
                    $.ias({
                        'history': false,
                        'triggerPageTreshold': 1,
                        'trigger': 'Load more',
                        'container': '#ajaxProductListView',
                        'item': '.ademo',
                        'pagination': '#ajaxProductListView .pager',
                        'next': '#ajaxProductListView .next:not(.disabled):not(.hidden) a',
                        'loader': 'Loading...'
                    });
                }",
            ));?>
```